# Elasticsearch json query for recommendations

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, recommendation-engine, elastic-stack

I am currently trying to run an aggregation query to elasticsearch index to do recommendations.

**Data that im pushing to elasticsearch using logstash**

```
OrderNumber ProductName
o12345      Chicken         
o55631      Peanuts   
o12345      Apples
o98356      Avocado
o12345      Oranges
o31498      Peach
o12345      Grapes
```

As you can see above Order Number **o12345** is Unique which contains all products that was purchased for that order.

After the data is passed into Elasticsearch i get the following formatted output :

```
"_index" : "hello",
      "_type" : "logs",
      "_id" : "AVmxZxg-pyZuCjD89WOe",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "message" : "o12345\Chicken\r",
        "@version" : "1",
        "@timestamp" : "2017-01-18T11:47:20.518Z",
        "path" : "C:\\Elk\\logstash\\bin\\mylog.log",
        "host" : "localhost",
        "OrderNumber" : "o12345",
        "ProductName" : "Chicken"
}, { 
"_index" : "hello",
          "_type" : "logs",
          "_id" : "AVmxZxg-pyZuCjD89WOe",
          "_score" : 1.0,
          "_source" : {
            "message" : "o55631\Peanuts\r",
            "@version" : "1",
            "@timestamp" : "2017-01-18T11:47:20.518Z",
            "path" : "C:\\Elk\\logstash\\bin\\mylog.log",
            "host" : "localhost",
            "OrderNumber" : "o55631",
            "ProductName" : "Peanuts"
```

I am trying to Query this data in order to get the following result :

- If I purchase "chicken" what other products was purchased with chicken. So in actual fact i need to Query the order number for chicken which is **o12345** and bring back all products besides chicken.

**Example**

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
        "ProductName" : "Chicken"
}
```

Now return all other products that was purchased with chicken which is Unique to o12345 which are

```
OrderNumber ProductName
    o12345  Apples
    o12345      Oranges
    o12345      Grapes
```

Please help i am new to elastic and unsure how to formulate this query.

Comment: This is not exact your use case, but you do terms aggregation on OrderNumber and a nested terms aggregation on ProductName. This will give you back buckets like `"o12345" : ["Apples", "Oranges", "Grapes"]`. Another option would be to do two queries, one to get OrderNumbers for Chicken and then query for all documents with that OrderNumber. This approach scales better.

Comment: @khachik , Thank you for your response it was very helpful however i am still puzzled as to how to query my dataset. If you have some time please have a look at another question i have posted. link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806896/quey-elasticsearch-jason      thank you very much